# Flex/ActionScript: Support for localizing numbers and dates?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, localization

Does Flex/ActionScript offer support for localizing numbers and dates to a user's particular region?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex supports it.  Here's an entire chapter from the Flex docs on localizing apps:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/l10n_1.html

Here's a section on localizing dates, times and currencies:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/l10n_7.html#161909